# Sonata Admin adding custom variable to ListMapper

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

This is how I currently do it, is there a better way, or more proper way?

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
     $this->sale_type_arr = array('1'=>'Value1','2'=>'Value2');

     $listMapper
          ->add('saleType','string', array(
            'template' =>  'AppBundle:ItemAdmin:list_saleType.html.twig',
            'label'=>'saleType'
        ))
        ...
}
```

And my template file like this:

```
<td>
{% if object.saleType !='0' %}
{{ attribute( admin.sale_type_arr, object.saleType) }}
{% endif %}
</td>
```

It all works fine, no problem, just doesn't feel right. There should be a way of how to directly inject array value, based on Items database value inside add(..).

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I do not advise you to use {{ attribute(...) }} in field. The scope is completely hidden when visualising your template.

A better solution is to set directly the associative array in template. It is not ideal in architecture point of view, but offers you best code visibility.

See what I propose below (I write all necessary code for the complete template):

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field %}

    {% set sale_type_arr_custom = {1: 'Value1', 2: 'Value2'} %}
    {% if object.saleType !='0' %}

        {# Additionaly, protect for unknown key #}
        {% if object.saleType in sale_type_arr_custom|keys %}
            {{ sale_type_arr_custom[object.saleType] }}
        {% endif %}

    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```